# Vector operation with Python

Tags: python, geometry

I would like to calculate `c1` in `P1Q1` and `c2` in `P2Q3`.

[image]

At the moment, I have this code

```
def geometric_definition_fuzzy_standard_w(Q1, P1, Q2, P2, Q3):
    O_ = (P1[0] + P2[0]) / 2, (P1[1] + P2[1]) / 2
    OQ2 = Q2[0] - O_[0], Q2[1] - O_[1]
    OP1 = P1[0] - O_[0], P1[1] - O_[1]
    OP2 = P2[0] - O_[0], P2[1] - O_[1]
    P2Q2 = OQ2[0] - OP2[0], OQ2[1] - OP2[1]
    P1Q2 = OQ2[0] + OP2[0], OQ2[1] + OP2[1]
    P1Q1 = OP1[0] + P2Q2[0], OP1[1] + P2Q2[1] # HOW CAN I GET c1???
    P2Q3 = OP2[0] + P1Q2[0], OP2[1] + P1Q2[1] # HOW CAN I GET c2 ???
    longitude_P1Q1 = math.sqrt(P1Q1[0] ** 2 + P1Q1[1] ** 2)
    longitude_P2Q2 = math.sqrt(P2Q2[0] ** 2 + P2Q2[1] ** 2)
    input(longitude_P1Q1)
    input(longitude_P2Q2)
```

geometric_definition_fuzzy_standard_w((1, 30), (2, 5), (3, 20), (4, 5), (5, 30))

And I'm calling the function like this

```
geometric_definition_fuzzy_standard_w((1, 30), (2, 5), (3, 20), (4, 5), (5, 30))
```

My output

```
15.132745950421556
15.033296378372908
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Don't post your homework here. Post what you have tried and where exactly you're failing?

Comment: Homework? I'm trying to replicate a project. @GauriShankarBadola

Comment: @M.Spiller get c1, and c2...

Comment: Yes, you've posted that, but what specific problems are you having getting it? FWIW, numpy / pandas could help you here

Comment: I don't know how calculate it @cricket_007

Comment: It's an arbitrary constant. You can rearrange the equation to solve for those variables...

Comment: Yes but how? Because I was reading and I found the division to two vectors don't exist @cricket_007

Comment: You should clarify the problem. c1 and c2 are just a mathematical way to represent the geometric relation between P1Q1 and P2Q2 (and P2Q3 and P1Q2). Try to get c1 and c2 by just inverting the operation: (P1Q1-OP1)/P2Q2. You should get a scalar representing the relation between them. Notice that you can't divide vectors but due to the geometric representation you should be able to divide both components of the vectors separately and get the same scalar proportion.

Comment: Vectors can only be added and subtracted, sure. Are you able to talk to a professor / coworker / mentor about these projects?

Comment: This is a math question. Off topic for Python/coding.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I don't know anyone can help me with this! @cricket_007

Comment: Question: what is the purpose of the function? It's not returning anything. Why do you need those values?

Comment: Because I'm trying to replacate a geometry pattern stocks detector and  once we have found c1, c2, one way we can compare other
W shapes to the standard W by comparing how scaled their egde vectors
are compared to the standard c1, c2 @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

As this is about a *standard shape W* you know that `P1Q1` is parallel to `P2Q2`.

So `c1` is simply the quotient of the lengths of `P1Q1` and `P2Q2`.

IOW: how much do you have to scale `P2Q2` so that you are `P1Q1` long.

Comment: Well, I get `1.66666`. For simplification imagine all points having the same `x`-coordinate. `P1Q1` has length `25`, `P2Q2` has length `15`. Which results in `c1` being `25/15 = 1.666666`. For your values, the value will be slightly less.

Comment: I deleted the last comment. I add the lines and output of `|P1Q1|` and `|P2Q2|` and the output was `15.132745950421556` and `15.033296378372908`. How can I proceed?

Comment: Your code for calculating `P1Q1` and `P2Q3` is wrong the way you have written it above. Fix that by calculating it the same way as `P1Q2`

Comment: YES! I get 1.6666! So know How I should proceed? This is my c1?

Comment: Yes. That's `c1`. `c2` can be calculated the same way. As a proof you can afterwards calculate `P1Q1` again by using the equation in your picture above.

Comment: How can calculate `P2Q3`? I cant find the formule... Something like this: `P2Q3 = Q3[0] - P2[0], Q3[1] - P2[1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207682/discussion-between-m-spiller-and-martin-bouhier).

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of the solution in terms of a programming language

The idea is that point Q1 is offset in the X coord by a factor of the distance from O to P1, then offset additionally by some scalar c1 in the XY coord by a factor of the vector defined as P2Q2.

This is possible by the fact that the W shape has parallel lines.

To calculate the coefficients, you need to individually calculate the distance formulas and ratios between each pair of x and y coordinates from Q1 to Q2 and P1 to P2, and similarly in the opposite direction

In other words, what multiple of P2Q2, offset in the X coord is equal to the same vector as P1Q1?

Note that there are implicit points, let's say W1 and W2, that exist on "y=0" and directly underneath the outermost Q points

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical idea behind the equations for `c1` and `c2` is to demonstrate that there is a relation between `p1q1` and `p2q2` (similarly, `p2q3` and `p1q2`). Notice that the relation for standard shape W doesn't state that `p1q1` is parallel to `p2q2`, but that the `p1q1` is the result of the translation of `op1` and proportional in shape to `p2q2` (that is `c1`). Maybe the image helps to understand this part. The same applies to `c2`.

[image: op1]

Also, notice that the relation implies that `c1` and `c2` are scalars; meaning that the proportionality must be the same in both components. You cannot divide vectors but you can divide their components. This allows you to calculate `c1` and `c2` per component (thus, being able to solve each equation).

Next, I provide the code to calculate `c1` and `c2` by calculating the value from each component and testing that it is the same. For the sake of clarity, I have included lots of debug messages and a plot for the input points. You can disable them by just executing `python -O geometric.py`.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# For better print formatting
from __future__ import print_function


# Helper methods
def calculate_vector(p1, p2):
    return p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1]


def add_vectors(v1, v2):
    return v1[0] + v2[0], v1[1] + v2[1]


def draw_points(points):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Draw points
    x_values = [p[0] for p in points]
    y_values = [p[1] for p in points]
    plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)

    # Set chart properties
    plt.title("Geometry")
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")

    # Show chart
    plt.show()


# Main method
def geometric_definition_fuzzy_standard_w(q1, p1, q2, p2, q3):
    # Calculate O
    if __debug__:
        print ("Calculating O...")
    o = (p1[0] + p2[0])/2, (p1[1] + p2[1])/2
    if __debug__:
        print ("O: " + str(o))

    # Calculate vectors
    if __debug__:
        print ("Calculating vectors...")
    p1q2 = calculate_vector(p1, q2)
    oq2 = calculate_vector(o, q2)
    op2 = calculate_vector(o, p2)

    p1q1 = calculate_vector(p1, q1)
    op1 = calculate_vector(o, p1)
    p2q2 = calculate_vector(p2, q2)

    p2q3 = calculate_vector(p2, q3)
    p1q2 = calculate_vector(p1, q2)

    if __debug__:
        print("POINTS:")
        print ("Q1: " + str(q1))
        print ("P1: " + str(p1))
        print ("Q2: " + str(q2))
        print ("P2: " + str(p2))
        print ("Q3: " + str(q3))
        print ("0:  " + str(o))
        print()
        print("P1Q2 = OQ2 + OP2")
        print ("P1Q2: " + str(p1q2))
        print ("OQ2:  " + str(oq2))
        print ("OP2:  " + str(op2))
        print()
        print("P1Q1 = OP1 + c1*P2Q2")
        print ("P1Q1: " + str(p1q1))
        print ("OP1:  " + str(op1))
        print ("P2Q2: " + str(p2q2))
        print()
        print("P2Q3 = OP2 + c2*P1Q2")
        print ("P2Q3: " + str(p2q3))
        print ("OP2:  " + str(op2))
        print ("P1Q2: " + str(p1q2))
        print ()

    # Assert that p1q2 = oq2 + op2
    if __debug__:
        print("Checking p1q2 = oq2 + op2...")
    p1q2_calculated = add_vectors(oq2, op2)
    if p1q2_calculated != p1q2:
        print ("ERROR: Assert p1q2 = oq2 + op2 invalid")
    else:
        print ("p1q2 = oq2 + op2 OK")

    # Calculate c1
    if __debug__:
        print ("Calculating c1...")
    c1_0 = (p1q1[0] - op1[0])/p2q2[0]
    c1_1 = (p1q1[1] - op1[1])/p2q2[1]
    if c1_0 != c1_1:
        print ("ERROR: C1 is different for each component (" + str(c1_0) + " != " + str(c1_1) + ")")
    else:
        print ("c1 = " + str(c1_0))

    # Calculate c2
    if __debug__:
        print ("Calculating c2...")
    c2_0 = (p2q3[0] - op2[0])/p1q2[0]
    c2_1 = (p2q3[1] - op2[1])/p1q2[1]
    if c2_0 != c2_1:
        print ("ERROR: C2 is different for each component (" + str(c2_0) + " != " + str(c2_1) + ")")
    else:
        print ("c2 = " + str(c2_0))


    # Draw points
    if __debug__:
        draw_points([q1, p1, q2, p2, q3, o])

    # Return c1 and c2
    return c1_0, c2_0


# Entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    P1 = (15, 0)
    P2 = (25, 0)
    Q1 = (0, 10)
    Q2 = (20, 5)
    Q3 =(40, 10)
    C1, C2 = geometric_definition_fuzzy_standard_w(Q1, P1, Q2, P2, Q3)

    #geometric_definition_fuzzy_standard_w((1, 30), (2, 5), (3, 20), (4, 5), (5, 30))
```

Debug Output:

```
Calculating O...
O: (20, 0)
Calculating vectors...
POINTS:
Q1: (0, 10)
P1: (15, 0)
Q2: (20, 5)
P2: (25, 0)
Q3: (40, 10)
0:  (20, 0)

P1Q2 = OQ2 + OP2
P1Q2: (5, 5)
OQ2:  (0, 5)
OP2:  (5, 0)

P1Q1 = OP1 + c1*P2Q2
P1Q1: (-15, 10)
OP1:  (-5, 0)
P2Q2: (-5, 5)

P2Q3 = OP2 + c2*P1Q2
P2Q3: (15, 10)
OP2:  (5, 0)
P1Q2: (5, 5)

Checking p1q2 = oq2 + op2...
p1q2 = oq2 + op2 OK
Calculating c1...
c1 = 2
Calculating c2...
c2 = 2
```

[image: Geometry input points]

Performance Output:

```
p1q2 = oq2 + op2 OK
c1 = 2
c2 = 2
```